# Can re.findall() output be a list solely matched string?

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting a list of item names from a html code (see below)

```
[<p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Klasisch 1 Säulen Grün S</p>, <p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Klasisch 3 Säulen Braun L</p>, <p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Klasisch 3 Säulen Braun M</p>, <p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Klasisch 3 Säulen Grün M</p>, <p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Mit Hängematte Grün L</p>, <p class="a-text-left a-size-base">Weinachten 3 Säulen Grün L</p>]
```

Then,  I did regular expression to extract the names

```
var_text = re.findall(r'>.+?<', str(varyasyonlar_text))
```

then, the output have been again list but with the charesters "<" ">", which I don't want to.

```
['>Klasisch 1 Säulen Grün S<', '>, <', '>Klasisch 3 Säulen Braun L<', '>, <', '>Klasisch 3 Säulen Braun M<', '>, <', '>Klasisch 3 Säulen Grün M<', '>, <', '>Mit Hängematte Grün L<', '>, <', '>Weinachten 3 Säulen Grün L<']
```

I only want to clean a list with the captured names. My question is now, how can I modify my regex command.

Thank you so much

Comment: Simply use a capturing group for the part that should be reported.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use parenthesis to capture the result you want and to eliminate getting comma values, just add a negation for it

```
> : match literal
[^,] : don't match ","
.+? : non greedy match all characters
< : end of pattern

re.findall(r'>[^,](.+?)<', str(varyasyonlar_text))
```

```
['lasisch 1 Säulen Grün S',
 'lasisch 3 Säulen Braun L',
 'lasisch 3 Säulen Braun M',
 'lasisch 3 Säulen Grün M',
 'it Hängematte Grün L',
 'einachten 3 Säulen Grün L']
```